# jquery button with path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery dialog with 3 buttons. It displays when there is a specified error.
What i want is to add different paths to each of the buttons, so when a user clicks on it he is redirected to another page or action of the controller.

HTML:

```
//new.html.twig

<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Atention Doublon">
    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:30 7px 10px   10;"></span>{{person.prenom}} {{person.nom}} est déjà enregistré</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 200,
                width: 500,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Add": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "edit": function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Could someone assist me with this? Please also mention if there are any errors in my code as this is quite possible, I am not too familiar with jQuery.

Comment: Just add something like `window.location = "http://www.mozilla.org";` in each buttun `function()`. See http://jsfiddle.net/7Zvqp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Or

```
window.location.href("http://www.google.com");
```

Thus:

```
buttons: {
    "Add": function() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    "edit": function() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.goole.com');
        $(this).dialog("close");
    },
    cancel: function() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.google.com');
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to look into the `onclick` function, which you can attach to buttons.  This will allow you to redirect via href, or else run a function of your choice for each button.

Examples: `<Button onclick="myFunction()">` or in JS `object.onclick=function(){JSCodeHere};`

Answer (score 0):

I think you using Symfony2, So you can  install this [bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle), and you can generate url from JavaScript like this : `Routing.generate('my_route_to_expose', { id: 10 });`

Answer (score 0):

It should just be as easy as this:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Faf24/)</kbd>

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 500,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Add": function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://google.com';
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "edit": function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://yahoo.com';
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        cancel: function() {
            window.location.href = 'http://microsoft.com';
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

---

Please also note that you have not specified a jQueryUI stylesheet, so your dialog / lightbox may not display correctly. Note the **link** tag

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
```